# AngularJS ng-style vs.style - ng-style does not refrest automatically

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code to upload my profile image:

```
file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                    vm.currentUser.profileImagePath = response.data.profileImagePath;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }, function (re ...
```

and with this code the image is refreshed/reloaded after upload and works fine

```
<div class="userProfileItem userProfileImage" style="background-image: url(api/files/profileimage/{{vm.currentUser.profileImagePath}}/)">
```

except that I get sometimes the following Browser error:

> 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:8082/api/files/profileimage/%7B%7Bvm.currentUser.profileImagePath%7D%7D/"

Therefore I have changed code to this one at the bottom. But with the code at the bottom the image is not refreshed automatically.

```
<div class="userProfileItem userProfileImage" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(api/files/profileimage/{{vm.currentUser.profileImagePath}}/)'}">
```

My question now would be how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You had `{{}}` interpolation inside `ng-style` expression, which is not required there. You could directly get access to scope variable there, use concatenation to form expression.

```
<div class="userProfileItem userProfileImage" 
  ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(api/files/profileimage/'+ vm.currentUser.profileImagePath +'/)'}">
```